# CSV file getting downloaded twice

Tags: php

I am using following code to download csv file.

```
static function download(){

        $wooe_download = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'woooe_download', FILTER_DEFAULT);
        $wooe_filename = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'filename', FILTER_DEFAULT);

        if( !empty($wooe_filename) && !empty($wooe_download) && file_exists(path_join( self::upload_dir(), $wooe_filename.'.csv'))
            && wp_verify_nonce($wooe_download, 'woooe_download')
        )
        {
            $charset    =   get_option('blog_charset');
            $csv_file   =   path_join( self::upload_dir(), $wooe_filename.'.csv');

            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". self::filename());
            header("Expires: 0");
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Content-Encoding: '. $charset);
            header('Pragma: public');
            //header('Content-type: text/csv; charset='. $charset);
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($csv_file));
            //header("Pragma: public");
            readfile($csv_file);
            //unlink($csv_file);
            exit;
        }
    }
```

File is getting downloaded twice in browser. I am not sure how to restrict it to only once?

Comment: that function must be being called twice, so the answer is not in that function - where is that function being called

Comment: I am calling a url using javascript. It is being called only once.

Comment: if you put the url directly into the browser  does it download twice ?

Comment: I would say your issue is in your javascript code, probably you forgot to use `preventDefault()` without the javascript code & an example trigger we cannot help further.